# What is the best way to retrieve any object from Mongo using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, model-view-controller

I have a server which must store and retrieve objects from a given collection "/foo". I can do this if I know the structure of the objects but I now it must extends in a general way: store any object and retrieve any object. What is the best way to do it with MongoRepository and in a Controller-Entity-Repository way?

Comment: Industry standard is to get post variables from a URL and return JSON.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the object structure to allow people to help you with a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoCollection` can handle custom object entities. Initialize the collection as below and find the object.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("foo");
Document queryDoc = new Document();
queryDoc.append("col", "value");
queryDoc.append("col", "value");
FindIterable<Document> result = collection.find(queryDoc);
```

Document - https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start/

You can also use Filters - https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html